# how to make chrome extension to work for the protocol "file://*"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, translation

extension:[ImTranslator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh)

for example: i wanna read Chinese version of the `JDK 1.8 JavaDoc(offline file)`,however the extension dont work in `file://*`.
How to modify to make ImTranslator effective?

Comment: Can you include `manifest.json` at Question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this permission to the `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "file://*/*"
]
```

The user has to manually approve this by visiting `chrome://extensions/` and checking "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox (unless the extension is loaded from your local disk).

In your code, you can see whether file access is allowed using:  [`chrome.extension.isAllowedFileSchemeAccess`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-isAllowedFileSchemeAccess).

Comment: thanks,then it still doesn't work after checked this check box "Allow access to File URLs" and modified  file `manifest.json`.

Comment: @Amelie Can you include any relevant code or explain what exactly you need to do, so I can help in case there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @LukaČelebić - Thanks. Works for me with `file://*`